# Backup and restore Zookeeper database

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, database-restore

I would like to significantly expand on the question that had been asked about two years ago in this thread: [How do you backup Zookeeper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394140/how-do-you-backup-zookeeper)

How do you not only backup Zookeeper database, but more importantly, what is the best practice to **restore the database** from a backup, especially, if you are running a **cluster/ensemble of Zookeeper servers**?

There is no document at the project web-site that would explain the restore procedure for a distributed deployment. The home-grown solution that involves stopping the whole cluster, wiping out databases on all but one server, restoring the database on one server, and then bring up the cluster and pray that the populated server becomes the leader and populates the cluster. Such solution seems to be too error-prone.

Does anyone have recommendations on how to make it robust?

Maybe there is a way to force-populate the ensemble remotely?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Exhibitor seems to do some of the things mentioned in the question: http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/04/introducing-exhibitor-supervisor-system.html